# Incompatible type: ´method pointer and regular procedure´

Tags: delphi

Tenho um calendário somente com mês/ano e criei um "evento" pra que, quando fosse selecionado, o mês pudesse ser tratado e os campos preenchidos.

```
type
  TonAnoMesSelecionadoEvent = procedure(Sender,Parent:TObject;Mes,Ano:Integer);

  TCalendario = class(TwinControl)
    ....
    Procedure pnlMesClick(Sender:tobject);
  private
    FMes,FAno:Word;

  protected
     //FonAnoMesSelecionado :TonAnoMesSelecionadoEvent;
  public
    FonAnoMesSelecionado:TonAnoMesSelecionadoEvent;{tem a propriet mas removi ela pois achei que o erro era esse}
    constructor Create(AOnwer: TComponent);  overload; override;
    constructor Create(AOnwer: TComponent;X,Y:integer);overload;
    constructor Create(AOnwer: TComponent;X,Y,ano:integer);overload;
    procedure pShowCalendar(AOnwer: TComponent;X,Y:integer);
  end;

  .....

  procedure TfrmCalendario.pnlMesClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if Assigned(FonAnoMesSelecionado) then
      FonAnoMesSelecionado(Self,Owner,TPanel(Sender).Tag,btnAnos.Tag);
  end;
```

O problema ocorre ao tentar associar minha *procedure* a este `Field`:

```
 Tform1 = Class(Tform)
  ....
   procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
   procedure onSelect(Sender,Parent:TObject;Mes,Ano:Integer) ;
 end;



   Procedure tform1.btnClick(sender:tObject);
   var
    lCalendar:TCalendario;
  begin
    lCalendar:TCalendario.Create(self);
    lCalendar.FonAnoMesSelecionado := OnSelect;//<- erro ocorre nessa linha
    //lCalendar.pShowCalendar(.....);
    //......
  end

  procedure tform1.onSelect(Sender, Parent: TObject; Mes, Ano: Integer);
  begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Mes)+'/'+IntToStr(Ano));
  end;
```

Não sei como posso fazer isso, o que está errado???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definição do tipo tem que ser `TonAnoMesSelecionadoEvent = procedure(Sender,Parent:TObject;Mes,Ano:Integer) of object;`

Comment: Bah! tinha esquecido do `Of object`.  Valeu!!!!